# Is it possible to use a frontend framework only on one page in an already finished project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'm working on a project where I need to make a dashboard as a homepage like this

> https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/reference-samples/DynamicDashboard/angular/dist/

but in the project we don't adopt any frontend framework, only JavaScript and jQuery.
The project used Django as a backend.

Comment: Yeah but I would suggest making a move to transform the entire project to use a framework... Anyways if you're using a framework there's a good chance you can bundle the project into a few files and serve as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a small piece of Vue somewhere in a project without managing a whole lot, you could probably use [petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue).
This is somehow similar to [Alpine](https://alpinejs.dev/) and perfect if you want to add just a small piece of interactivity, while staying in the Vue ecosystem.